# Enable change image on hover then disable based on class being active jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an ajax website and on the home page I am changing some images on hover with a function I call on dom ready, the code I use for this is below

```
function darkText() {
    $('#home,#home2,#home3,#home4').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).attr({
            src: $(this).attr('data-other-src') 
            , 'data-other-src': $(this).attr('src') 
        })
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    darkText();
});
```

With this ajax site there are 4 boxes where these image are displayed, and as said once hovered over the images, they change. Each image links to an ajax page, and once opened the relevant image they clicked on is displayed again. I would like to disable the hover function when the ajax page is opened.

In my code there is a div with the class `box` for each image, and once the image has been clicked an additional class which is `active` is appended to the `box` class. Could I use this active class in anyway to disable the function when active is visible in the class, and then re enable when active is not in the class.

The code where active appends is below:

```
<div id="about" class="box"> <--------- THIS IS THE CLASS WHERE 'ACTIVE' APPENDS
      <div class="header">
        <div class="special-title">
          <nav>
            <h2 class='top'><a href="#" onclick="checkForWorkChange()"><img id="bg-home" data-other-src="dark.png" src="light.png" alt=""></a></h2>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="desc invisible">
          <h2>

          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
content here....
</div>
```

Sorry, it's a little confusing to explain on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
You can probably just wrap the attribute setter in an if statement.

```
if (!$(this).parents(".box").hasClass("active")) {
  // set attributes here
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/j745btwp/1/

**Solution 2:**
Hover effects can be probably done only via css. Just need the click event 
 that will add "active" to your .box element in javascript.

```
<div id="about" class="box">
  <a class="picture" href="#">
    <img class="default" src="https://images.waiv.host/home/work.png" alt=""/>
    <img class="onHover" src="https://images.waiv.host/home/work-dark.png" alt=""/>
  </a>
</div>
<style>
.picture {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 120px; /* pic height */
  width: 240px; /* pic width */
}

.picture img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.picture .onHover, .picture:hover .default {
  display: none;
}

.picture:hover .onHover {
  display: block;
}

.active .picture .onHover {
  display: none !important;
}
.active .picture:hover .default {
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/j745btwp/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can add the style rule `pointer-events: none` to **.active** css class. This will disable all mouse pointer based events, like click, mouseenter, etc.